# how to hide previous in every click of table row?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

[image]

can u see the output in this screenshot. now what is the problem is.

In left table i have two rows that is dynamic. Right side am getting output.

If I click first row of left table i should display output of that row in right side. That is working.

Same If I click second row of left table I should display second row output only but its displaying first row and second row output. Its not hiding the first row output.

It displaying each and every row multiple times for every click

Please help me out friends am new to jquery so i don't know how to solve this.

My Code - index.php

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#table_struct tr').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var height = $this.height();
        var order_id = $this.data('order_id');

        $.get('getuser.php?order_id=' + order_id, function(table) {
        $('.menu').append(table);
        $('.menu').css({
        right: offset.right,
        top: offset.top+height
        });
        });
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
        session_start();
        include "db.php";
        $query = "select * from purna_orders";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_rows >= 1)
            {

            echo "<div id='showmenu' class='scroll'>";  

        echo "<table id='table_struct' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' border='1' width='400' height='30'>
             <tr class='tr_class' bgcolor='white'>
             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Select </td>
             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Order Id </td>
             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Customer Name </td>

             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Price </td>

             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Pincode </td>
             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> COD </td>
             <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Status </td>




        </tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                    $order_id = $row['order_id'];
                    $_SESSION['order_id'] = $order_id;
                    echo "<tr height='20' data-order_id='".$row['order_id']."'>
                    <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' class='case' name='case' value='1'></td>
                    <td align='center'>".$row['order_id']."</td>
                    <td align='center'>".$row['customer_name']."</td>

                    <td align='center'>".$row['order_value']."</td>

                    <td align='center'>".$row['bill_to_pincode']."</td>
                    <td align='center'></td>
                    <td align='center'>Ready To Ship</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    }


    if(!mysql_close($con))
    {
        echo "failed to close";
    }   

        ?>
        </body>
```

getuser.php

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    $order_id = intval($_GET['order_id']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM purna_order_items WHERE order_id = '".$order_id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<div style=margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;'>";
    echo "<table border='1' style='background-color:white; font-style:bold;'>
    <tr>
    <td align='center'><b>Increment Id</b></td>
    <td align='center'><b>Po Order Id</b></td>
    <td align='center'><b>Item Sku</b></td>
    <td align='center'><b>Item Name</b></td>
    <td align='center'><b>Item Price</b></td>
    <td align='center'><b>Item Quantity</b></td>
    <td align='center'><b>Item Weight</b></td>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['po_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['sku'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['item_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['item_price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['item_quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
    mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can first remove the existing output on the click event and then the new record will be append.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#table_struct tr').click(function() {                 
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var height = $this.height();
        var order_id = $this.data('order_id');

        $.get('getuser.php?order_id=' + order_id, function(table) {
            $('.menu').empty(); // First remove the existing record from DOM
            $('.menu').append(table);
            $('.menu').css({
                right: offset.right,
                top: offset.top+height
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Glad i could be of help :)